# Google colab keeps disconnecting

Tags: google-colaboratory

I've encountered an issue on Google Colab that I'd like to address. Occasionally, without any predictable pattern, my runtime disconnects (refer to the attached image), resulting in the loss of all progress made and the termination of the session.

This problem occurs sporadically and isn't tied to a specific runtime duration or the code being executed. **Interestingly, it doesn't seem to be triggered by inactivity either, as it can happen while I'm actively engaging with the page.** The disconnection abruptly wipes out any work I've done, and upon reconnecting, the session resets, causing complete data loss.

[image]